# Mattermost, slash command response as message attachment

Tags: php, json, mattermost

I have this block of code that builds a message attachment and/or a table for the response of a slash command;

```
$attachments = array();
if (!count($whereClause)) {
    $data .= "**Can Not Build Query**\n";
}
else {
    if ($data = $db->getResult($sql)) {
        $table = "| PRC | Part Number | BIN | WH | Last Edit | Quotes | Last Quoted | Orders | Units Sold | Total Sales | Last Sold |\n";
        $table .= "|----:|----------:|----:|----:|--------:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|\n";

        foreach ($data as $part => $value) {
            $res_prc = $value['PRC'];
            $res_pn = trim($value['Part_Number']);
            $res_bin = $value['Bin'];
            $res_wh = $value['WH'] ?: 'N/A';

            if (isset($value['Last_Edit'])) {
                $res_le = date_format(date_create($value['Last_Edit']), 'm/d/Y');
            }
            else {
                $resl_le = 'N/A';
            }

            if (isset($value['By'])) {
                $res_le = $value['By']." @ $res_le";
            }

            $res_qts = $value['Quotes'] ?: 'N/A';

            if (isset($value['Last_Quoted'])) {
                $res_lq = date_format(date_create($value['Last_Quoted']), 'm/d/Y');
            }
            else {
                $res_lq = 'N/A';
            }

            $res_odr = $value['Orders'] ?: 'N/A';
            $res_us = $value['Units_Sold'] ?: 'N/A';
            $res_ts = $value['Total_Sales'] ?: 'N/A';

            if (isset($value['Last_Sold'])) {
                $res_ls = date_format(date_create($value['Last_Sold']), 'm/d/Y');
            }
            else {
                $res_ls = 'N/A';
            }

            $attachment = array(
                "fallback" => "PRC: $res_prc Part Number: $res_pn Location: $res_bin",
                "text" => "PRC: $res_prc Part Number: $res_pn Location: $res_bin",
                "color" => "#3fdbbc",
                "author_name" => "PRC: $res_prc Part Number: $res_pn",
                "title" => "$res_bin",
                "title_link" => "http://http://devbox/vrf/binlist.php?binLoc=$res_bin",
                "title" => "$res_bin",
                "fields" => array()
            );

            $warehouse = array(
                "short" => "true",
                "title" => "Warehouse",
                "value" => "$res_wh"
            );
            array_push($attachment['fields'], $warehouse);

            $last_edit = array(
                "short" => "true",
                "title" => "Last Edit",
                "value" => "$res_le"
            );
            array_push($attachment['fields'], $last_edit);

            $table .= "|$res_prc|$res_pn|$res_bin|$res_wh|$res_le|$res_qts|$res_lq|$res_odr|$res_us|$res_ts|$res_ls|\n";
            array_push($attachments, $attachment);
        }  
        $attachments = json_encode($attachments);
    }
    else {
        if ($db->lastError) {
            $data = "Error {$db->lastError} in:\n$sql";
        }
        else {
            $data .= " __No results__ \n";
        }
        $table = $data;
    }
}

$response = array(
    'response_type' => 'ephemeral',
    // 'text' => "$table",
    'username' => "Woodhouse",
    'icon_url' => 'http://linux3/mc-dev/img/woodhouse.png',
    'attachments' => "$attachments",
);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

---

If I use the code as is mattermost logs and reports that the slash command has returned an empty response. If I uncomment the text node in the response array, I get a table as expected. If I remove the `$table` variable from the text node in the response array and replace it with the `$attachment` variable i get the following printed in the response inside mattermost;

```
[
    {
        "fallback": "PRC: TI  Part Number: MC1489N Location: GG-68-06",
        "text": "PRC: TI  Part Number: MC1489N Location: GG-68-06",
        "color": "#3fdbbc",
        "author_name": "PRC: TI  Part Number: MC1489N",
        "title": "GG-68-06",
        "title_link": "http://http://devbox/vrf/binlist.php?binLoc=GG-68-06",
        "fields": [
            {
                "short": "true",
                "title": "Warehouse",
                "value": "W1"
            },
            {
                "short": "true",
                "title": "Last Edit",
                "value": "jlapera @ 09/11/2006"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Which would be expected since it's the data that is put together for the attachment.

Also, I commented out setting the content type before echoing the response and I get the JSON of the entire payload as a response when the command is run.

Am I missing something in my formatting? or something?

---

EDIT: 4/11/18

I ran into this issue again, and ultimately what I did to keep my code as clean as possible was;

```
$mmst_attach_raw = (object) [
      "fallback" => "Discrepancy Update or Recorded",
      "color" => "#BA1200",
      "author_name" => $attachment['created_by'],
      "title" => "Discrepancy Alert",
      "title_link" => $attachment['links']['edit'],
      "fields" => [
        [
          "short" => true,
          "title" => $attachment['order_type'],
          "value" => "[".$attachment['order_num']."](".$attachment['links']['tracker'].")"
        ], [
          "short" => true,
          "title" => "Department: $attachment[department]",
          "value" => "Created By: $attachment[created_by]\nLast Save: $attachment[last_action_by]"
        ], [
          "short" => false,
          "title" => "Vendor: $attachment[vendor_name]",
          "value" => "Vendor Number: $attachment[vendor_num]\nTerms: $attachment[vendor_terms]\nWarehouse: $attachment[warehouse]"
        ], [
          "short" => true,
          "title" => "Part Number: $attachment[part_num]",
          "value" => "Manufacturer: $attachment[prt_mfg]"
        ], [
          "short" => true,
          "title" => "$attachment[issues]",
          "value" => "$attachment[description]"
        ]
      ]
    ];
    $new_mmst_msg = array(
      'text' => "Incoming Alert",
      'channel' => '@mcarpenter',
      'attachments' => array($mmst_attach_raw)
    );

    send_msg_mmst($new_mmst_msg);
```

I had to create an attachment object first, I then added it to the attachment key by putting the object in an array, and then emitting it to my send message function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with PHP, but it looks like you might be sending the attachments field as a string instead of an array of objects since you have `'attachments' => "$attachments"` there. The final json payload for the response should look something like

```
{
    "response_type": "ephemeral",
    "text": "<text>",
    "username": "Woodhouse",
    "icon_url": "http://linux3/mc-dev/img/woodhouse.png",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text": "<attachment text>"
        }
    ]
}
```